# An application of Gronwall's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I want to apply Gronwall's inequality on the differential inequality$$
y'(t)\leq Cy(t)^b
$$
where $C$ is a constant and $b>1$. I was wondering if, in the differential form, I can simply define $\beta(t)=Cy(t)^{b-1}$ and rewrite the previous inequality as$$
y'(t)\leq \beta(t)y(t),
$$
since $\beta$ is only required to be real-valued and continuous. Then, I would have that $y(t)$ can be estimated by the solution of the ODE $z'(t)=Cz(t)^b$, which is roughly $z(t)=Ct^\frac{1}{1-b}$. Thus$$
y(t)\leq Ct^\frac{1}{1-b}.
$$
Is this correct or is there something I'm not seeing?

PS - I have heard of the Bihari-LaSalle inequality, but I'm not sure whether I need to go there.

Comment: No. $\beta(t)$ has to be independent of $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as $y(t)$ is positive you can divide by $y(t)^b$ and then integrate
$$
y(t)^{-b}y'(t)\le C\implies y(0)^{1-b}-y(t)^{1-b}\le (b-1)Ct 
$$
so that
$$
y(t)\le \frac{y(0)}{\Bigl(1-y(0)^{b-1}(b-1)Ct\Bigr)^{1/(b-1)}}.
$$

Comment: How did you get the last inequality? I got it reversed.

Comment: With $u(t)=y(t)^{1-b}$ we get $$u'(t)=-(b-1)y(t)^{-b}y'(t)\ge -C(b-1)C,$$, note that $b-1>0$. Then $$u(t)\ge u(0)-C(b-1)t$$ and thus $$y(t)^{b-1}\le\frac{y(0)^{b-1}}{1-y(0)^{b−1}(b−1)Ct}.$$ That is, the inequality sign changes direction twice, first by negation and then by the inversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the inequality with $\beta(t) = Cy(t)^{b-1}$, but your conclusion is incorrect: what it actually tells you is that $y(t)$ can be estimated by the solution of $z'(t) = Cy(t)^{b-1}z(t),$ so you're left with the integral inequality $$y(t) \le y(0)\exp\left(\int_0^t Cy^{b-1}(s) \,\mathrm ds \right),$$ which I doubt is any help.

I would instead follow the path of combining the Grönwall inequality with a local Lipschitz estimate: let $z(t)$ be the solution of $z'=Cz^b$ with initial condition $z(0)=y(0)$ and consider the difference $u=z-y$, which we want to show is non-negative. From the ODE for $z$ and the differential inequality for $y$ we find $$u'(t) \ge C\left( z(t)^b - y(t)^b \right).$$

Suppose that $u(t_1) < 0$ at some time $t_1 > 0,$ and let $t_0$ be the last time at which $u \ge0,$ so that $z(t_0)=y(t_0)$ but $z(t) < y(t)$ on $(t_0,t_1].$ Since $[t_0,t_1]$ is compact and $b\ge1$, there is some constant $M$ such that $z(t)^b-y(t)^b \ge M(z(t)-y(t))$ on this interval, and thus we have $u'(t) \ge CMu(t).$ Applying Grönwall to this inequality on $[t_0,t_1]$ shows $u\ge 0$, a contradiction.