# How to understand correctly the differential inequalities?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, integral-inequality

The question comes from reading the question and the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642276/an-application-of-gronwalls-inequality).

Let us consider a specific example,
\begin{equation}
y'(x)\le \frac{1}{2}y^2(x), \quad 1>x\ge 0
\end{equation}
which satisfies the conditions of [Bihara's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihari%E2%80%93LaSalle_inequality) (differential form).
Therefore, one can obtain
\begin{equation}
y\le -\frac{2}{x},
\end{equation}
i.e., by substituting $y(0)=-\infty$ and $C=1/2$ in @Lutz Lehmann's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642276/an-application-of-gronwalls-inequality).

In contrast, let us check the result $y\le -\frac{2}{x}$. we know that
\begin{equation}
-\frac{2}{x^2}\le -\frac{2}{x}, \quad \text{when}\quad 1>x\ge 0,
\end{equation}
thus I expect that $y=-\frac{2}{x^2}$ must satisfy the initial inequality.
However, if we substitute it into $y'(x)\le \frac{1}{2}y^2(x)$, we get
\begin{equation}
x\le 1/2,
\end{equation}
which of course contradicts to $y'(x)\le \frac{1}{2}y^2(x)$ when $x\in (1/2,1)$.

So what's the problem here?

Comment: The claim is: If a function satisfies the differential inequality, then it is bounded. A function satisfying the bound can oscillate wildly below the bound, not satisfying the differential inequality.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is me who misunderstands the meaning of the differential inequality.